# Does netlogo extension rngs work in the new version?

Tags: netlogo

Building off my last post, I'm trying to draw a random-beta distribution using the rngs extension of netlogo but none of the primitives seem to be working for me. Does this extension (build for netlogo 4.1) work for the new version? If not, is there a new extension that can help me draw the distribution?

If it does, then I have to assume it's a code error on my part. As per the guide at: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions My code is currently:

```
extensions [rngs]

to setup
make_turtles
end

to make_turtles
create-turtles 10000


ask turtles 
[
 rngs: init
 rngs: set-seed
 let dist rngs: rnd-beta random-float 999 0.9 0.5
 set target_Factor dist
]
end
```

This is the first time I'm employing an extension so I very well may be confused as to how they work, even though I have RTFM, but that to me is what the guide says to do...

Summary of errors:
for the code above I get "nothing named RNGS has been defined"
If I remove the ":" I get "nothing named init has been defined" so it looks to me like it's not reading the primitives correctly, or am I employing it wrong?

Comment: This builds off the post at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493122/draw-a-random-beta-distribution-in-netlogo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error:

`rngs: init` should be `rngs:init`. Note that there is no space after the colon.

The "no-space-after-the-colon rule" should be the case for *all* extensions when calling their procedures (i.e. `table:make` or `array:item`).

Comment: it's always the little things!

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to do this in the future, here is the correct code (I've double checked it using the histogram plot inset). I want the random number seed and stream ID to vary, so I set them to random-float of some arbitrary large number.

```
extensions [rngs]

turtles-own [target_factor]
to setup
  clear-all
make_turtles
end

to make_turtles
create-turtles 1000

ask turtles 
[
 rngs:init
 let stream_id random-float 999
 let seed random-float 999
 rngs:set-seed stream_id seed
 let dist rngs:rnd-beta  stream_id 0.8 0.5
 set target_Factor dist
]
set-current-plot "plot 1"
histogram [target_factor] of turtles
end
```